# .NET Image Libraries

Tags: c#, image

What are some good image libraries for C#? Mainly for things such as painting in layers. Or maybe a resource that can describe similar tasks?

Comment: Are you talking about *images* or drawing libraries? The System.Drawing namespace should have enough to get you started (using GDI).

Comment: Image libraries, to mainly add images to a picturebox, or custom control, and make each image its own, so that it can be manipulated seperately.

Comment: Do you care what language the library is written in, as long as you can use it from C#?

Comment: There is also [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

With [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx):

```
Image GetLayeredImage(int width, int height, params Image[] layers)
 {  Point layerPosition = new Point(0,0);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width,height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
     { foreach(Image layer in layers) g.DrawImage(layer, layerPosition);
     }
    return bm;
 }
```

In the above example, a method, *GetLayeredImage()* is defined that accepts the width/height of the composite image, along with an array of `Image` objects, one for each layer. A point at (0,0) is defined as the top-left position for each layer. A `Bitmap` object is created and from that a `Graphics` object is created for drawing onto the bitmap. Each image in the array is then drawn onto the bitmap at the point (0,0)—you may want to change this by creating a different `Point` value for each layer. The resulting bitmap is then returned. The return value is an image with all the layers drawn.

Here's an example on how to call this method:

```
Image layer1 = Image.FromFile("layer1.jpg");
Image layer2 = Image.FromFile("layer2.jpg");
Image layeredImg = GetLayeredImage(width,height,layer1,layer2);
pictureBox.Image = layeredImg;
```

Comment: Could you explain using the Drawing/Graphics already in .NET to create layers which can be switched to allow movement of images based on the layer?

Comment: I added some info about animated GIFs.

Comment: Hmm, Not exactly what I meant. I didnt mean Animated images when I referred to movement. I was actually meaning the position of the image allowing to be moved separated by layers, much like paint.net, but a much more simple form.

Comment: Im a total newb. Can you explain this piece of code a bit, or how to properly implement the code you provided?

Answer (score 2):

[GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx)+ comes installed with .NET

Answer (score 0):

I've used the third-party tool called LeadTools Imaging Pro SDK with great success.

http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing/default.htm

Usually anything like Paint.Net functionality will be obtained by way of third-party software or a lot of coding on your part.

Comment: Im just looking for some basic functionality. Much like any diagramming software, like Visio for instance. I dont need photoshop like features, just some basics to add some things to a picturebox, and be able to move around the individual pieces when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Leadtools and [Atalasoft DotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) are both pretty good. I've had good luck with Leadtools. You can use the builtin system.drawing features with Leadtools and probably DotImage.

Comment: Also, FreeImage is a free open source option.