# What are the best practices to validate Image and upload in ASP.Net Core/EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, image-upload

I have found some questions like [Validate Image Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282205/validate-image-type-for-iformfile-in-asp-net-core) but it didn't fulfill my needs.
I have Model class named `Movie` which contains property

`public byte[] Image { get; set; }`

My **View contains**

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input asp-for="Image" type="file" id="files" class="form-control" />
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

and in controller, I am converting it to **bytes** and storing it in database. I want to validate it like, Files allowed **.jpg**, **.jpeg**, **.png** and max size of file **5Mb**.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Movie Movie, List<IFormFile> Image)
    {
        foreach(var item in Image)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    Movie.Image = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        _applicationDbContext.Movie.Add(Movie);
        _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

How can I validate the uploaded file ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code,rather post the code itself

Comment: ok, i will edit my question, thanks for feedback

Comment: and why not check the filename(with extension) for known image extensions ??

Comment: and in order to check the size , take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380839/how-do-you-get-the-file-size-in-c)..I mean u can use `FileInfo.Length` and set an if condition,that's all(Note that `length` will return the file size in bytes,u may need to do the conversion)

Comment: display it on the screen? retrieve it?

Comment: @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs NO, Just want to validate Image only to prevent it form File Upload Vulnerability. I want to validate it like, Files allowed *.jpg*, *.jpeg*, *.png* and _max size_ of file *5Mb*.

Answer (score 1):

Every file has an extension and if it is a binary file, it has magic numbers in the header of the file that indicates what type of file it is, You can identify file type by reading the header of bytes.

Check this GitHub code

https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective

file headers reference:

http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

mime types reference:

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml